# Flutter - Error: The argument type 'Image' can't be assigned to the parameter type --- solution?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm just starting to learn Flutter and when trying to add an image with a network image as the source, I encountered this error. I tried to search solution for this but still can't find it. So anyone could enlighten me on what the problem could be ?. Thank you.

Here is the source code

```
 Error: The argument type 'Image' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>'.
```

- 'Image' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart' ('/C:/src/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/image.dart').
- 'ImageProvider' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart' ('/C:/src/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart').
- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
  image: Image.network(

Comment: Have you tried `NetworkImage()`

Comment: Can you include your image snippet

Answer (score 4):

There are two way to show network image in flutter.

First use `NetworkImage`

```
Image(
  image: NetworkImage('https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/chihuahua-dog-running-across-grass-royalty-free-image-1580743445.jpg?crop=0.446xw:1.00xh;0.254xw,0&resize=480:*'),
)
```

or use:

```
Image.network('https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/chihuahua-dog-running-across-grass-royalty-free-image-1580743445.jpg?crop=0.446xw:1.00xh;0.254xw,0&resize=480:*')
```

Answer (score 0):

While NetworkImage is a image provider, Image or Image.network are Widgets so you need to use Image.network() or Image class

Answer (score 0):

This error mainly cause just because you are providing "Image" rather then "ImageProvider".

code:

```
              Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: NetworkImage(
                            "https://picsum.photos/250?image=9"),
                        ),
                    ),
              )
```